# modern frontEnd architecture using module loader

Tags: angular, reactjs, vue.js, frontend

I'm a bit confused about modern frontEnd architecture/folder organisation.

In all the most popular frameworks (angular, react, vue), I see the following:

```
/src
----/app
----app.main.js
index.js
```

**index.js** is the entry point of the application, is the file where our app is bootstrapped.

**app.main.js** is the *real* entry point of our app.

Let's say I have some global variables to define or third part libraries to include (js & css).

Where should I import them?

Comment: quite broad question. but in general you import libraries and assets where you need them.

Comment: @dfsq, If I need them in multiple files I need to import each time?

Comment: by just looking at the folder structure of a project it is impossible to understand how to do implementation with that framework

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi, nobody talk about implementation

Comment: ok, `{...prevCommnet, implementation:using}` :)))

Comment: never used `index.js` in a react application. we do have a main javascript file with the root component. We do not import anything there.

Comment: If you guys are down-voting, please explain why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a broad one. I need to specify a framework to answer you, I will choose **Vue.js**.

On Vue, you have some structures that all your components can access, like: `plugins`, `store` and `route`. These guys can be imported once, in your `index.js` (or `main.js`).

## App file

---

In this case (Vue), your `App.vue` doesn't import anything but the needed to render it. This file `App.vue` is a component, its name is only a pattern, you can name it as you want. For instance, if you will only create a component to your old website, you won't create an App, you will only create a component (maybe a Callendar). Then, you don't need to create a file called `App.vue`.

## Global Imports

---

The "global imports" are the mentioned above (plugins, store, route etc). They are imported and initiated on `main.js`.

#### Plugins

For `plugins` (a structure used like `services and/or factory` in Angular) you can import using in `main.js`:

```
import Auth from './plugins/Auth'
Vue.use(Auth)
```

Obs: I use plugins to organize my requests. They are available for all my components, I just call using `this.$auth.me().then(...)`.

#### Store and Route

For these two cases, we create an index.js for each one.

```
/
    src/
        router/
            index.js
        store/
            index.js
        App.vue
        main.js
```

Each one has a special structure to import "addons" to it. But both of them I import on `main.js` on this way:

```
import Store from './store'
import router from './router'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store: Store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {App}
})
```

## Important

---

In ES6, if you use  `import` statement, it will import just once. Then, you can import the same library in all your files, but it will import just once.

Answer (score -1):

In the case of Vue.js the structure actually usually looks like this:

```
/
  src
    main.js
    App.vue
```

Where `main.js` could be considered a "bootstrapper" and is a good place to put global libraries and variables. `App.vue` Is the entry point of the application proper and has some UI semantic to it, usually containing things like the top level layout and router view.

Different frameworks will have different best practices.